# Collecting various theories on toy examples: Projective space

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, big-list

I am looking for text books/notes/papers/documents playing with toy examples: projective space, in particular, $P^{1}$. Because I think this is really a cute example. Although algebraic geometry on $P^{1}$ is comparatively simple, it gave inspirations to treat more general situtation. Precisely, I am looking for something including following topics:(but you can add whatever you want)

1. algebraic geometry of $P^{n}$, say, $Coh(P^{n})$, $D^{b}(Coh(P^{n}))$, say, exceptional collection,semi-orthogonal decomposition,stability conditions
2. Relation to representation theory, say, Hall algebra of $Coh(P^{n})$ and $D^{b}(Coh(P^{n}))$ and its relation to affine quantum group: $U_{q}(\hat{sl_{n+1}})$, representation theory of Kronecker quiver. Tilting theory. Weighted projective line and so on.
3. $D-module$ on flag variety of $U(sl_{2})$(or $P^{1}$) and so on..................
4. Add whatever you like.
5. Add whatever you like.

..................................................

Comment: I approve of this question :)

Comment: various things ?? Please talk mathematics instead. 

Comment: I mean various mathematical subjects, but do know not how to express precisely

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I can answer this question by myself now. I did some literature research and find some papers and notes illustrating $P^{1}$ to establish various theory
[Lectures on Hall algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611617)
The author talks about Hall algebra of coherent sheaves on $P^{1}$, relation with representation theory of $U_{q}(\hat{sl_{2}})$ and also [The Hall algebra of the category of coherent sheaves on the projective line](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906037v1) talks about similar facts.

[Twisted rings of differential operators on the projective line and the Beilinson-Bernstein theorem.](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/koush.pdf) It is a master thesis by Koushik Panda. He established $P^{1}$(flag variety of $sl_{2}$) version of Beilinson-Bernstein localization. His treatment is very detailed.

[t-stabilities and t-structures on triangulated categories](http://iopscience.iop.org/1064-5632/68/4/A04/pdf/IZV_68_4_A04.pdf?ejredirect=migration)illustrates classifications of t-structures on $D^{b}(Coh{P^{1}})$
[Introduction to coherent sheaves on weighted projective lines](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4473) by Chen-Xiaowu and Henning Krause. Very expository notes for coherent sheaves, Tilting theory, derived category of $P^{1}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert, but I think it's unlikely you're going to find much literature that focuses only on the projective line. But, for example, almost every algebraic geometry book I know uses the projective line and higher dimensional projective spaces as a basic example for everything. And, if a paper or book does not discuss explicitly these examples, then I think that is an opportunity for a student to work it out on his or her own.